# .getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path) caches result

Tags: java

I load a file at a servlet, use .getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path), path is in WEB-INF/classes dir, I found after I changed path file content, but file servlet loads are the same, don't change, file is cached.

example code:

This method always gets the same result every time, after I change the test.key content

```
private String getKey(String param){
    String name = "keys/"+param+"/test.key";
    InputStream in = XXXServlet.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            builder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException ignoreException) {

    }finally{
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    String result = builder.toString();
    return result;
}
```

=================================================================

change these two lines code, it works fine

```
    String name = "/WEB-INF/classes/keys/"+param+"/test.key";
    InputStream in = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(name);
```

Comment: Most probably what is happening is that the classloader that is used to load XXXServlet does resource caching, because nothing is defined in the classloader's specification so it's up to the implementation to decide to cache or not. So after the first getResourceAsStream you'll always get the cached version, although you can only be sure of it looking at the specific implementation. When delegating to your ServletContext most probably it doesn't cache (if you're using tomcat I can assure you it doesn't) and you have the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Ankur is right.  An existing class loader trying to get a class or resource (regardless of the name and path to the file/inputstream) will never reload if the name and associated content has already been loaded once by the class loader or it's parent.  This is for performance reasons.  The only way to do it is to create a new instance of a class loader and do it again.  But then, at least with classes, you'll have to worry about incompatible classes running together in the system.  Like you can't assign an instance of the new class to a variable that was typed with the class loaded by the first class loader instance since they're technically different classes.

Pabrantes thinks it is different because Liu is not loading a 'class' per say, but a key:  "keys/"+param+"/test.key";  However he's using the classloader to do so and the rules are the same on loading 'name' with respect to getResourceAsStream(name).  Doesn't matter if it's a class or not, classloader will think "Oh here you go, I've already loaded the byte stream for 'name'".  Pulls it right out of permgen.  For those interested - if you create/implement your own version of a new classloader that reloads every time - just make sure it only does this for very specific paths or name patterns.  Also keep in mind that every copy you load will likely get space in permgen so over time permgen will grow out of control unless you unload.

So - that's why it doesn't work.  ContextLoader is good to use. :-)

Dan C.

Answer (score -1):

This is because once you have loaded a class, you will get the same class contents even if you try to reload it. This is because it checks if the class contents are already loaded, if yes then it does not bother to load it once again just refers to the one already loaded(in memory).

To achieve reloading you need write a custom class loader, which will read the contents of the class (in bytes) and use these bytes to load the class.

Sample CustomClassLoader code :

```
public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

private static final String CLASS_FOLDER_PATH = "/lib/all-classfiles/";
private static final String CLASS_FILE_EXTENSION = ".class";


/**
 * Loads the class file in memory
 */
@Override
public Class<?> loadClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return findClass(className);
}

@Override
protected Class<?> findClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    try {

        byte[] bytes = loadClassData(className);

        // Build the class based on the byte data
        return defineClass(className, bytes, 0, bytes.length);

    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        // Call super class(ClassLoader) implementation of loadClass() method
        return super.loadClass(className);
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the byte contents of the class file
 * 
 * @param className
 * @return byte[] - class file data
 * @throws IOException
 */
private byte[] loadClassData(String className) throws IOException {

    File classFile = new File(CLASS_FOLDER_PATH + className + CLASS_FILE_EXTENSION);

    int fileSize = (int) classFile.length();

    // Read the file bytes in byte array
    byte buff[] = new byte[fileSize];

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    DataInputStream dis = null;

    fis = new FileInputStream(classFile);
    dis = new DataInputStream(fis);

    // Read the byte contents of the ORM class file for loading the class
    dis.readFully(buff);

    dis.close();
    fis.close();

    return buff;
}
```

}

Make sure that your class loader instance is garbage collected when you want to reload the contents of the class. Or else you may end up reading cached class data.

There are many more things you need to take care of while reloading. Please read this article on [Class Reloading](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html) to understand it in detail.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think you're addressing the issue here, the original poster is asking a question regarding a non class resource and your answer is regarding class resources. Also you have a bug in your classloader implementation you're always defining the class data, you can only do that once per class per classloader, so you would have to discard one classloader and use another to redefine the new modified class. Usually hot reload is done by having a custom classloader like the one you did but with an inner class loader that you can be discard when needed to hot reload the class.

Comment: I have just provided a sample example of custom class loader. While using this class to load any class, you need to create instance of it and make sure it gets discarded before reloading it, which I have mentioned in my answer. So please do read the entire answer before placing your opinion or claiming that the code contains bug.

Comment: I'm sorry but I've read the entire answer Ankur, and in my opinion (notice it's MY opinion) I don't think it's clarified in your answer anywhere that you would need to create a new instance of your CustomClassLoader each time a hot class reload would be needed. Also *I* would expect that if one class loader claims to do hot reload then *I* could use *always* the same instance to load the class several times. The code you present for your custom class loader creates no difference between creating a new instance every time  of your custom class loader or a "non custom" class loader.

Comment: It does make difference Pabrantes. I have used the same code before to reload classes dynamically. It is not the case that I have copy pasted the code from some links, this code was used by me few months back and works fine.